# ASP/Javascript onClientClick SecurityCheck()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink, onclientclick

Hey want the javascript after it has been cofirmed to link to another aspx file, but somehow it won't direct the browser to the url. here is what i got

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Donebtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/done.jpg" ToolTip="Done. Add new activity" CommandName="Done" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ActivityID") %>' OnClientClick="return SecurityCheck();" />
```

javascript

```
function SecurityCheck() 
  {

      return window("Mark Activity as completed and add new Activity?");
      if (o == true) 
      {
          window.location.href = 'CustomerHome.aspx?CustomerId=<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>';

      }
      else 
      {
          return window("No changes will be made");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `o` object? You need to use following:

```
function SecurityCheck() 
{
  var answer = confirm("Mark Activity as completed and add new Activity?");
  if (answer) 
  {
      window.location.href = 'CustomerHome.aspx?CustomerId=<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>';
  }
  else 
  {
      alert("No changes will be made");
      return false;
  }
}
```

**[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/3NjZb/8/)**

Comment: thanks but it still doesnt redirect to the link. I guess it doesnt understand the format of the link?

Comment: actually i just replaced the link with http://www.google.com and it wont direct it there either. hmm

Comment: I've added live example. I don't know why it's not working on your environment, bute make sure that your function if visible globally.